# How to set height of table cell "display: table-cell"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

I used table for calendar, there I set:

```
td, th {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

there possible to set td height ?

**Example**: Is below code possible?

```
display: table-cell;
height: 25px;
max-height: 25px;
```

Please help to set td height.

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: `display` for table cells should already be `table-cell`. `td,th{ height:25px; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following css..It will work for your requirement

```
td,th{ 
height:25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`table` is already  `display: table-cell;` (by default) 
[image] 
**However you can set `height`**

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 25px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tell me for more help